# Google image search using google custom search and google api key returns not expected result

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-custom-search, google-apis-explorer

I  am trying to make a google image search, using google custom search engine, and a Google API key,  to return a response, then from the response body, extract the URL, title and text snippets that describe the result. I get a result, but the result doesn't contain the items array, and the result's searchInformation's totalResults = 0: there has to be an image of cats on the internet. What it returns, I commented out, just before the ending curly braces and bracket of the app.route method's HTTP verb.

Please this question has been researched, and there are similar questions, here at StackOverflow, but they have not been answered. I don't know if maybe because the questions didn't have 'google-apis-explorer' tag

```
app.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res) {
         var endPoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' + API_KEY + '&cx=' + 
        CSE_ID + '&q=cats&num=10&searchType=image&start=1'
      https.get(endPoint, (response) => {
      const statusCode  = response.statusCode;
      const contentType = response.headers['content-type'];

      var error;
      if (statusCode !== 200) {
    error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                      `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
  }     else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
    error = new Error('Invalid content-type.\n' +
                      `Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`);
  }
      if (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    // consume responseponse data to free up memory
    response.resume();
    return;
  }

      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      var rawData = '';
      response.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; 
  });
      response.on('end', () => {
    try {
      res.send(JSON.parse(rawData));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
}); 
  //res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/views/index.html');
})



// what it returns. 
{
    "kind":"customsearch#search",
    "url":{
     "type":"application/json",
      "template":"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"
    },
    "queries":{
        "request":[
                    {
                        "title":"Google Custom Search - lectures",
                        "totalResults":"0",
                        "searchTerms":"cats",
                        "count":10,
                        "startIndex":1,
                        "inputEncoding":"utf8",
                        "outputEncoding":"utf8",
                        "safe":"off",
                        "cx":"013162268872379598895:76khcwygut4",
                        "searchType":"image"
                    }
                ]
    },
    "searchInformation":{
        "searchTime":0.340305,
        "formattedSearchTime":"0.34",
        "totalResults":"0",
        "formattedTotalResults":"0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but my image search option was not enabled. So, check whether image search is enable on created search engine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. image search was enabled

Comment: My bad. you're right. the image search needs to be enabled. I guess as I've been trying to solve the problem, for long, my brain is no longer working properly

Answer (score 0):

> The answer to my question. You should make sure of the following in the custom search engine; image search is enabled. You will have to extract the image from the items array.